# how to access excel individual sheet, apply a function, and collapse result in R?

Tags: r

I want to read a multiple sheets into R and I was able read them using the following code:
library(gdata)

```
dataFile <- file.path('.../Desktop/readMultiSheetExample.xls') 

dat<-NULL; for (i in 1:2) { dat[[i]]<-read.xls(dataFile,sheet=i,head=T) }

Sheet 1
obs cens
2.9 D
1.7 D
1.2 U
7.4 D
1.2 U

Sheet 2
obs cens
2.4 D
0.5 D   
1.4 U
1.5 U 
0.4 U
1.1 U
1.1 U
```

I wrote a simple function to give simple stats.  How can write a code that would allow me to access individual sheet and calculate summaryStats for each individual sheet and then combine the result for each sheet into a nice table.

For each sheet, I would like
     # modify second column
     data$cens <- ifelse(data$cens == "U", 1,0)

```
summaryStats <- function (data)
{   
obs <- data$obs
cens <- data$cens

n <- length(obs)
nCens <- length(cens)

maxValue <- max(obs)
minValue <-min(obs)

result <- data.frame(n,nCens,minValue,maxValue )
names(result) <- c('N','N.Censored',"Min",'Max')
return(result)
```

Comment: Maybe you're missing `lapply` call to your `summaryStats` function. What `lapply` does is visits each list element and applies the provided function to the contents of the element (in your case, a data.frame).

Comment: could you please be more specific as to where I should use lapply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `lapply` to run a function on each list element and `rbind` to combine the results.

```
dat <- lapply(dat, summaryStats)
result <- do.call(rbind, dat)
```

Comment: I got the error message:  Error in Summary.factor(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  : 
  sum not meaningful for factors

Comment: @Amateur, there you go, tidy your data frame column classes and you'll be on your way!

Comment: @RomanLuštrik:  I am very sorry that I still don't understand what you mean.  I am very new to R programming.  I don't understand what the error message mean so I cannot fix my code.

Comment: @Amateur Factors are a specific data type for categorical and ordinal variables; you can't really do math operations a categorical variable.  That suggests that your numeric "obs" variable is being read in as a factor.  1) Factors are a big pain when you don't explicitly need them, so I start almost all of my scripts with `options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`.  2) Try typing `str(dat)` to see what your data types are.  `obs` should be numeric, `cens` should be a character (factor would probably be okay, too).

Comment: Thanks Matt Parker.  I know what the problem is now.  If I just code D as 0 and U as 1 in excel and the do apply, I would not have to deal with the categorical variable and the above code works just fine.

Comment: I suspect your `obs` column may be a factor, and you can't calculate a summary you would expect with factors.